# search between two sql tables

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have two tables `'Account_Position'` and `'Account'` linked with a column `'Account_id'`.

for one entry of `'Account_id'` in table `'Account'` we have multiple entries in `'Account_Position'` table.

I want to show all the records of `'Account'` table based on how many times they have occurred in  `'Account_Position'` table.

How can I show that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use Joins http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? You mention SQL Developer so presumably it's Oracle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
-- if you are using MSSQL, this query won't work because of 
-- asterisk in the select clause (you need to specify all the fields)
-- in the group by clause
-- (but it will work on MySQL)
SELECT  a.*, COUNT(b.Account_ID) totalOccurence   
FROM    Account a
            LEFT JOIN Account_Position b
                ON a.Account_ID = b.Account_ID
GROUP BY a.Account_ID
```

OR

```
-- alternatively, you can use this.
SELECT  c.*
FROM    Account c
        (               
            SELECT  a.Account_ID, COUNT(b.Account_ID) totalOccurence
            FROM    Account a
                        LEFT JOIN Account_Position b
                            ON a.Account_ID = b.Account_ID
            GROUP BY a.Account_ID
        ) d ON c.Account_ID = d.Account_ID
```

Comment: I think you can't select `*` with only gruoping by `id`in MSSQL :)

Comment: i really don't know what the OP is using but i assume it's MySQL. hehe

Answer (score 0):

conside 2 tables

Table1   (contains more the one row for a id)
col - nchar(10) -   Checked
id -    int - Checked

Table2
id   - int -    Checked
col1    - nchar(50) -   Checked
col2 -  nchar(50) -     Checked
col3 -  nchar(50) -     Checked

try the below query

select

*

from

```
Table2

inner join(

    select

        id as id, count(id) as cnt

    from

        Table1

    group by id

)A on

Table2.id = A.id
```